# Are small, portable medium-pressure washers susceptible to damaging some components when washing a bike (like with high-pressure washers)?

Tags: maintenance, preventative-maintenance

There are now on the market small, portable pressure washers meant for outdoor sports. Those are typically powered by batteries and have a water tank, to be used without a water supply and electricity. To give some names (no endorsement): Bosch Fontus, Kärcher OC3. Those are very convenient to quickly remove mud and dirt at trail heads, or in the street for those living in cities.

They are operating at much lower pressures than conventional pressure washers (5-20 bars vs 100-200 bars). But the beam is highly concentrated, and is shaped like the one of a high-pressure washer.

There have been already questions about washing bikes with [high-pressure](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/40910/power-washing-a-bicycle) and [garden hoses](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/is-it-really-going-to-damage-a-bike-to-wash-it-with-a-hose). But the question here is when using such washers, should they be handled as high-pressure washers, or is the pressure not high enough to cause the typical "damage" linked to high-pressure washers (damaging the bearings by washing out the grease)?

Comment: While I wouldn't use a high pressure washer at all, the chief aspect of washing a bike with a hose or other running water is where the water is aimed. If you avoid vulnerable bearing areas of the (especially external) BB, headset, ends of the hubs, and suspension pivots, if present, that's good practice. By "avoid" I mean limiting time, volume and pressure of water and cleaners in these areas. A bike enjoying a basic routine of maintenance that includes new grease on cleaned bearings and seats should hold up well to a year of nature's elements and an owner's fastidiousness.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

German MTB-News did test multiple portable power washers inlcuding the Kärcher OC3 and Bosch Fontus. While the Bosch has more power, they say both are strong enough that you should be careful with the bearings or turn down power on the Bosch.

Source: https://www.mtb-news.de/news/aqua2go-mobi-kaercher-mobile-wasserdruckreiniger-test/

Answer (score 2):

I managed to press water into my bottom bracket with just a garden hose with a spray nozzle.

Even with a "low pressure" pressure washer, do NOT spray directly at bearings. They should work well for other parts though.